# shrink a pargraph with microtype or other packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, graphics, pdftex, microtype

I need a little help to setup the microtype package: I need to shrink a sentence (not the whole document) in the footer (i use fancyhdr for page style).

the documentation is a bit complex for me (http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf), so i cannot find how to achive my task.

i use pdflatex

thank you in advance

```
\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gray] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\normalsize, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\normalsize, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {%
    A VERY LONG SENTENCE THAT NEED TO BE SHRINKED HERE!!!%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

---

As suggested by Gustavo Mezzetti, a better package is graphics with `\resizebox{...}{\height}{Some text}`. I'll give a try (thank you)

---

update: resizebox works perfectly. Update the code accordingly.

```
\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gray] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\normalsize, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\normalsize, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {%
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{10pt}{A VERY LONG SENTENCE THAT NEED TO BE SHRINKED HERE!!!}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: microtype is for "invisibly small" changes, don't you just want to use `\small` instead of `\normalsize` here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know I know, but i want to SHRINK the font (horizontally, not vertically), and to now I don't see other packages doing that...

Comment: without an example it's impossible to see what you want to do, or by how much you need to distort the font.

Comment: {’d say that what you are looking for is something along the lines of `\resizebox{...}{\height}{Some text}`, which requires the `graphics` package, not `microtype`.

Comment: Have you tried using `\footnotesize`?

Comment: please don't put answers in the question, you can post an answer (or ask @GustavoMezzetti to do that)

Comment: please @GustavoMezzetti post your comment as answer so we can close this post, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments and added as an edit to the question.